# Probability Uniform distribution shift smaller than some $\epsilon$

Tags: probability

I'm currently working through the Paper [Proving the Lottery Ticket Hypothesis: Pruning is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.00585), specifically I'm trying to understand the proof of Lemma A.1 in the appendix.

I'm stuck at: $$
\mathbb{P}\left[\left|w_{i}^{(j)}-\alpha\right| \leq \epsilon \wedge\left|u^{(j)}-1\right| \leq \epsilon\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[\left|w_{i}^{(j)}-\alpha\right| \leq \epsilon\right] \mathbb{P}\left[\left|u^{(j)}-1\right| \leq \epsilon\right]=\frac{\epsilon}{2} \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2}=\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{4}
$$

I do not understand how $\mathbb{P}\left[\left|w_{i}^{(j)}-\alpha\right| \leq \epsilon\right]$ is equal to $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

The important assumptions are:

- $w_{i}^{(j)}$ and $u^{(j)}$ are chosen randomly from $U([-1,-1])$
- $\epsilon \in (0,1)$
- $\alpha \in [0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}]$ ($s$ is some integer greater or equal than 1)
- $\alpha \geq \epsilon$

I think I understand $\mathbb{P}\left[\left|u^{(j)}-1\right| \leq \epsilon\right]=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, because the sample $u^{(j)}$ chosen from the uniform distribution gets shifted into $[0,2]$ and $\epsilon$ is a value in $(0,1)$. But I do not see the same for the $\alpha$ case. For example, if I fix $\alpha = 0.3, \epsilon = 0.2$, epsilon is out of the range the sample $w_{i}^{(j)}$ is getting shifted into ($\left|w_{i}^{(j)}-\alpha\right| \in [1-\alpha, 1+\alpha]$). The probability should be $0$ for this case. What am I missing?

Comment: As you mentioned $w_i^j$ follows uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$, so its density function is $1/2$ over $[-1,1]$. Assuming $\alpha-\epsilon \geq -1 $ and $\alpha+\epsilon \leq 1 $, $\mathbb{P}[|w_i^j-\alpha|\leq \epsilon]= \mathbb{P}[ 
\alpha - \epsilon \leq w_i^j \leq \alpha + \epsilon]$. Note that this probability only depends on the interval length which is $2\epsilon$.

Comment: @Mahdi You're right, of course -- but this would seem to give a probability of $\epsilon$, not $\epsilon / 2$, so I wonder if something has been lost in translation between the paper and this question.

Comment: I glanced at the paper, and it does look like it was accurately transcribed here. My lean is now that the paper contains a mistake and that it should be $\epsilon$ instead of $\epsilon / 2$, but I have not *carefully* vetted this so I may well have missed something. (This claim is part of a standard analysis proof that I think wouldn't suffer much from an $\epsilon$ vs $\epsilon /2 $ distinction, at any rate.)